# When I have to put my username and password in for GitHub on the command line, what is the username and password?

Tags: git, github

When I am cloning a repository from Github onto my device and it prompts me to put my username and password, is this my username and password the username and password I use to get into Github? I feel like the problem has to be deeper than me forgetting my password because I copy it exactly as the password that logs me into Github on Chrome.

It prompts me to put the username and password when I am on Step 4 and then fails. I am keying the code correctly, but I don't think I am putting in the right username or password or maybe something with my keychain access on the --global level or using ssh.

I am using macOSBigSur.

1. Open your preferred command line interface, which we'll call your shell from now on. Clone this repository: `git clone https://github.com/davidatoms/github-slideshow.git`
2. Navigate to the repository in your shell: `cd github-slideshow`
3. Create a branch, use whatever name you like. Feel free to use the suggested name below. `git branch my-slide`
4. **Push the branch to GitHub:** `git push --set-upstream origin <BRANCH-NAME>`

It prompts:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': davidatoms
Password for 'https://davidatoms@github.com':
```

I did delete the password in Keychain access to Github, I do have an ssh key that I have never used, and I have watched a couple of hours of tutorials on how to get it set up. I ran into this problem while I was trying to simply clone my "Getting Started with Github" from their new Github Lab.

I appreciate corrections and tips. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it is possible to perform Git access to GitHub over HTTPS using your username and password *unless* you have two-factor authentication set up.  However, this capability is going away, because using a password for this is not very secure, since any exposure gives an attacker to the entirety of your account.

If you are using 2FA now, and at some point in the future for all users, you need to use a personal access token to access Git.  You can [create one in the appropriate page under Developer Settings](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and you will need to create it with the `repo` scope.  You'll want to make sure that you have a suitable credential helper (on macOS, verify that `git config credential.helper` prints `osxkeychain`, which is the default).  Then, when prompted for your password, paste in the personal access token, and the credential helper will save it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I would like this, but I am brand new to the scene and don't have enough clout yet. I appreciate the work you're doing at Github as well. It's helping me learn.